# Axes not in order on plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I've been trying to show an area using coordinates. 
When I input the coordinates directly into a list, it shows the area.
But, when I use variables, it doesn't.

```
#plotting a triangle using coordinates
print('Enter the coordinates')
Na = input('Northings of A = ')
Ea = input('Eastings of A = ')

Nb = input('Northings of B = ')
Eb = input('Eastings of B = ')

Nc = input('Northings of C = ')
Ec = input('Eastings of C = ')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [Ea, Eb, Ec, Ea]
y = [Na, Nb, Nc, Na]
plt.plot(x, y, 'yellow')
plt.show()


x = [1500, 1720, 1244.52, 1500]
y = [5930.15, 6230.25, 3254.62, 5960.15]
plt.plot(x, y, 'purple')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide values in lists x and y?

Comment: `input()` returns strings, you have to cast the content of the variables to a numeric type to get the desired ouput

Comment: @gbajson the values are shown above

Comment: @DizietAsahi thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think casting to int from input was a problem and lack of Nd and Ed variable.

```
print('Enter the coordinates')
Na = input('Northings of A = ')
Ea = input('Eastings of A = ')
Nb = input('Northings of B = ')
Eb = input('Eastings of B = ')
Nc = input('Northings of C = ')
Ec = input('Eastings of C = ')
Nd = input('Northings of D = ')
Ed = input('Eastings of D = ')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [int(Ea), int(Eb), int(Ec), int(Ed)]
y = [int(Na), int(Nb), int(Nc), int(Nd)]
plt.plot(x, y, 'green')
plt.show()
x = [1500, 1720, 1244.52, 1500]
y = [5930.15, 6230.25, 3254.62, 5960.15]
plt.plot(x, y, 'purple')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!